# Upload text file on FTP server using iPhone

Tags: iphone, file, text, upload, ftp

I have implemented code for uploading images and directory to FTP using iPhone.

But I need to upload text file on FTP using iPhone. Can you please send me code for that.

Comment: Don't ask for code. Show us what you got and maybe we'll be able to help.

That being said, your question doesn't even look like one. If you can send binary files using FTP, sending text files should be a walk in the park.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-ipod-touch-sdk-development-discussion/328541-ftp-usage-iphone-applications.html

It uploads one byte at a time, so be sure your strings are ASCII encoded if you are expecting ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to upload entire directory including text, binary etc. files. It creates subdirectories as needed.

http://www.biterscripting.com/SS_FTPUpload.html

Start with that script and change it to suit your particular situation.